# how to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' in this specific code?

Tags: python, discord.py, pythonanywhere

I'm new to coding and I've been trying to make a simple discord bot, as an experiment, and I keep getting this when I try to run it on PythonAnywhere. I don't have this problem on repl.it though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/DELICTREAJay/somthingother/somoo.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "/home/DELICTREAJay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/DELICTREAJay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DELICTREAJay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/DELICTREAJay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Here is my code

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I have a separate .env file in the same directory where the token is kept

Comment: There are articles on the PythonAnywhere help pages that describe how to use .env files to set your environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specified variable named `TOKEN` in your environment variable. Just try to add a environment variable.

Comment: I have a separate .env file in the same directory where the token is kept

Comment: But the error means that your env file is not loaded. Or if it loaded Token is assigned as none Try to fix that problem.

Comment: I tried doing that but I don't really know how so it still failed.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `load_dotenv()`:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = "what you set in the .env file"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

hope this can help!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please edit your answer and insert your code directly to your answer instead of an image.

Comment: thanks for the advice